# How to connect to a 802.1x wireless network with EAP type to be SecureW2?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, network-manager

My school's wireless network supports 802.1x wireless connection with SecureW2 as EAP type.Is it possible to connect to this network from Ubuntu 12.04?I am asking because after a small google research that I did SecureW2 is only for Windows.

Comment: None of you have ever done this on Ubuntu?Iknow that it is possible I just do not know how.

Comment: Two things that might help - http://superuser.com/questions/34198/securew2-equivalent-on-linux/34234#34234, and http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1000786

Comment: However is interested: Check the superuser.com link above.